# How to exclude a tag in certain position within certain class with xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have this sample tag :

```
<div class='aaa'>
    <p>aaa</p>
    <div>bbb</div>
    <div>ccc</div>
    <div class='ddd'>
        <div>ddd</div>
        <div>eee</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I'd like to extract everything under `<div class='aaa'>` and exclude `<div>eee</div>`.

Number of tags that come under `<div class='ddd'>` may vary on runtime  with same depth but `<div>eee</div>` always comes the last.

So I tried using not(), last() like below, but so far none of it worked.

`//div[contains(@class,"aaa")]//(text())[not(@class="ddd" and position()=last())]`

How can I mend my xpath command to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you can't do what you want to do with xpath alone; you may have to use lxml or xquery.

Comment: @Jack Feeting Thank you. I'll have to go and see lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Initially fetch all elements like `//div[contains(@class,"aaa")]`. then pop the last element from the list and use `text()` to fetch all other text contents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that should return `aaa bbb ccc ddd`.

```
string-join((//div[contains(@class,"aaa")]//*[not(@class)])[position()<last()]/text(),' ')
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

If you don't want the spaces between the text() then change the string-join last argument accordingly.

**Option 2:**

```
string-join((//div[contains(@class,"aaa")]//text()[not(normalize-space(.)='')])[position()<last()],' ')
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind demonstration. xpath has interesting functions :)

Comment: does your issue is resolved. I wasn't sure about the output you are expecting, so gave the options.